# Integral $\lvert x(t) \rvert^2$ implies integral $\lvert x(t) \rvert$ and vice versa - Proof

Tags: proof-verification, education

I'm wondering if the following implications are true. If yes, how can I prove them?

$$
1. \,\,\,\,\, \displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty }^{+ \infty }} \lvert x(t) \rvert^2 \, dt \implies
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty }^{+ \infty }} \lvert x(t) \rvert \, dt
$$

$$
2. \,\,\,\,\, \displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty }^{+ \infty }} \lvert x(t) \rvert \, dt \implies
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty }^{+ \infty }} \lvert x(t) \rvert^2 \, dt
$$

I tried to prove them in this way. Consider two positive real constants $a$ and $b$.

$$
1. \,\,\,\,\, \displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty }^{+ \infty }} \lvert x(t) \rvert^2 \, dt = a < + \infty
\rightarrow
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty }^{+ \infty }} \lvert x(t) \rvert \, dt = \pm \sqrt{a}
$$
only the positive solution is correct because the integral of the absolute value is always $\geq 0$, thus:

$$
1. \,\,\,\,\, \displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty }^{+ \infty }} \lvert x(t) \rvert^2 \, dt = a < + \infty
\rightarrow
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty }^{+ \infty }} \lvert x(t) \rvert \, dt = \sqrt{a} < + \infty
$$

$$
2. \,\,\,\,\, \displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty }^{+ \infty }} \lvert x(t) \rvert \, dt = b < + \infty
\rightarrow
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty }^{+ \infty }} \lvert x(t) \rvert^2 \, dt = b^2 < + \infty
$$

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Those aren’t statements. You’ve written something like “$3.1\implies \tfrac12$” which is meaningless. Have you left something off? Perhaps “$<\infty$”?

Comment: What does it even mean to put a $\Rightarrow$ sign between two integrals? That's supposed to go between two claims that can be true or false, not between two expressions with that have (perhaps) numerical values.

Comment: **1)** what do you mean by $\int_{\mathbb R} |x(t)|^2dx\implies \int_{\mathbb R}|x(t)|dt$ ? **2)** Moreover $\int_{\mathbb R} |x(t)|^2dx=a\implies \int_{\mathbb R}|x(t)|dt=\sqrt{a}$ is completely wrong... What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: Hello @HenningMakholm, I mean that if the right side term is true, also the left side term is true.

Comment: But it is nonsense to speak about an integral being "true" or not. That's not something an integral can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write $\int |x(t)|^{2}$ as $(\int |x(t)|)^{2}$, so your arguments are wrong. Let $f (x)=\frac 1 {\sqrt {x}}$ for $0<x<1$ and $0$ elsewhere. Let $g (x)=\frac 1 x$ for $1<x<\infty $ and $0$ elsewhere. These two examples show that both implications are false.

Comment: I have made obvious changes to the question (like introducing $<\infty$ at appropriate places).

Comment: Hello @KaviRamaMurthy, the function $g(x) \ne f^2(x)$ because the domains are different; instead in my case I have two functions, one is $|x(t)|$, the other one $|x(t)|^2$. Can you explain your answer please.

Comment: What I mean is $\int |f(x)| \, dx <\infty$ and $\int |f(x)|^{2} \, dx =\infty$; also, $\int |g(x)| \, dx =\infty$ and $\int |g(x)|^{2} \, dx <\infty$. @GennaroArguzzi

Comment: Thank @KaviRamaMurthy so much for your explanation.